# Mist Testnet error "it seems this transaction will fail"

Tags: mist, gas, testnets, gas-estimate

I am very new to Ethereum, and just working through some early tutorials using the testnet. My version is up to date; the blockchain is also up to date; and I have only one account in the keystore, the main account.

As I try to deploy a simple contract (or any contract for that matter - including the examples on ethereum.org), the code compiles correctly:

[image]

When I go ahead and hit deploy contract, the confirmation popup gives me this error:  "it seems this transaction will fail. If you submit it, it may consume all the gas you send"

[image]

It gives me this error irrespective of whether I send 1 eth or 20eth, and regardless of the fee amount I choose.

If I press on regardless, the contract appears to be created on the mist wallet UI, but sits with another error message under the transaction saying basically that no data reached the blockchain: " No data is deployed on the contract address!".

My apologies if this is basic. I have scanned previous questions and they either didn't quite cover this scenario, or had a fix that didn't work for me (like reselecting the FROM account just before deploying)

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't send ether to this constructor or it will fail by design. If you want the opposite behavior then you specify the keyword "payable" in the function. It helps prevent errant transactions sending ether to contracts with no hope of recovering it.

Hope it helps.

UPDATE:

Example for clarity.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;
contract Example {

   string public brandName;

   function Example(string yourCompanyName) payable { // <--- here    
       brandName = yourCompanyName;
   }

}
```

As eluded to earlier, there is no way to make the contract send ether, so any funds deposited there are marooned. We could fix that with a simple indiscriminate withdraw function.

```
function withdraw(uint amount) public returns(bool success) {
   if(!msg.sender.send(amount) throw;
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Cheers Rob, the bytes 32 comments went over my head at this stage, however omitting an ether amount did prevent the error message and it did allow me to deploy the contract on the public test net. 
Many thanks for your answer - it fixed the problem i was having.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I updated my answer to concentrate on the solution that worked in this case.

Comment: if you provide some code examples with payable that would be good

Comment: @dark_ruby. Added example.

Comment: As mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40750913/error-sending-value-to-ethereum-smart-contract, From Solidity 0.4 onwards: A throw consumes all gas, so use `function t() payable returns (uint)`

Comment: two words for the ethereum developers: "ERROR CODES"

Answer (score -1):

having same issue using mist and testrpc , my code is

> ```
> contract sampletoken{
> mapping(address=>unit256) public balances;
> function sampletoken(unit256 initialsupply) payable
> {
> balances[msg.sender]=initialsupply;
> }
> }
> ```

get the same error when i deploy , you can find the screenshot at https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5BLz.png

Comment: This is not an answer and should not be in the answer field. Please move it to a comment for it to be more helpful.

Comment: @omkar khair  i dont have that much reputation

Comment: Comments shouldn't require reputation. Either ways, posting a question in the answer field isn't an option either. That would lead to a penalty in reputation.