# Contract not getting deployed when event traces are added

Tags: solidity, events

[image: Error message after deploying the below contract]I am not able to deploy the contract when event traces are added. 
Please help me figure out what is going wrong here. When I remove trial event() , I can deploy the contract.

```
pragma solidity 0.4.8;

contract X {

    address owner;
    uint amount;

    event test(address value);
    event trial(uint val);


    function X() {
        owner = msg.sender;
        test(msg.sender);
    }

    function invoke() payable {
        test(msg.sender);

        trial(amount);
        amount = amount + msg.value;

        trial(amount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

geth upate fixed the issue

C:\Users\deeph>geth version
Geth
Version: 1.5.9-stable

Answer (score 1):

More of a comment than an answer, but I wanted to add a picture. The above code works as expected in Remix, so this is possibly an unrelated issue with the way you're deploying it or transacting with it.

Remember the ABI includes information about the event interface, so if you change the contract, compile it (of course) and get the new ABI.

[image]

[{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"invoke","outputs":[],"payable":true,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"address"}],"name":"**test**","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"val","type":"uint256"}],"name":"**trial**","type":"event"}]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually, in Mist Wallet I get an error message indicating "No data is deployed in contract address". I will add screenshots to my original post

Comment: Prashant's comment above about gas is the main suspect now, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I tried replicating your issue at my end, but it works seamlessly.

```
Estimated fee consumption: 0.00244894 ether (122,447 gas) 
Provide maximum fee: 0.00444894 ether (222,447 gas)
Gas price: 0.02 ether per million gas
```

Please verify that you are providing sufficient gas to the contract and check if you need to update your wallet. Refer : [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12379/problem-publish-ethereum-contracts) and [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1582/mist-no-data-is-deployed-on-the-contract-address) for details.