# No data is deployed in the contract address

Tags: contract-deployment

I have followed the previous solutions to this problem as mentioned in this question: [Mist: "No data is deployed on the contract address!"](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1582/mist-no-data-is-deployed-on-the-contract-address)

I also checked if the `Estimated consumption fee is > Provide Max fee`. There were some cases when not using they keyword "**payable**" was the problem where `msg.value` was called. I have checked it as well. Still, I am getting "No data deployed"  error. Following is my code:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.8;

contract SGBFactory {

    event FundsReceived(address indexed sender, uint256 amt);
    mapping (address => uint256) public investmentFrom; 
    address public owner;

    modifier onlyOwner {
        if(msg.sender != owner) throw;
        _;
    }

    function SGBFactory() {
        // constructor
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function() payable {
        investmentFrom[msg.sender] += msg.value;      
        FundsReceived(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

}
```

Is there a problem in the code leading to this? The error message is not very helpful.

Comment: Could you kindly edit the question as it has some formatting problems?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa done :) .

Comment: Umm, it's still kind of messed up? :) http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: The code seems fine. Are you sure you've sent enough gas? Try sending 3mm gas just to make sure

Answer (score 1):

I was able to deploy this contract (it's on the Ropsten test network at address 0x70e91f8500667fd5e190f6ea31fc113b013a2067), and send Ether to its fallback function. I used a gas limit of 4,707,786 and deployed from remix.ethereum.org using MetaMask.

I'd suggest retrying with the above "settings" and see if it now works. There may have been a temporary issue with the network when you tried previously.

Hope this helps!