# Unable to deploy my smart contracts on testnet (Ropsten) with ethereumwallet or with web3

Tags: blockchain, contract-deployment, testnets, ropsten

I developed my smart contract using tesrpc. Now I want to deploy them on the testnet. But I am not able to deploy them either with EtherWallet (I have the error "No data is deployed in the contract address", even if I maxed the fees) or with a JS script using the web3 api where i set `Gas` to `4700000`. But i have no smart contract address back.

My smart contract code is:

```
pragma solidity ^ 0.4.2;

contract Color {


address public contracts;
string public color;


function Color(address _c, string _color) {
    contracts = _c;
    color = _color;
}


function getContracts() constant returns(address contractAddress) {
    return contracts;
}

function getColor() constant returns(string color) {
    return color;
}

function setlastDirAddress(address c) {
        contracts = c;
    }


function setColor(string clr) {
        color= clr;

}

}
```

EDIT: Here is my JS script:

```
    var Web3 = require('web3');
var solc = require('solc');
const fs = require('fs');

//Globals
var colorContract = {
    abi: null,
    address: null
};

//connect to testRPC / Geth locally
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
    // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
}

// Checking Ethereum connection status
if (!web3.isConnected()) {
    console.error("Ethereum - no conection to RPC server");
} else {
    console.log("Ethereum - connected to RPC server");
}

//Setting up the account 
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
var account = web3.eth.accounts[0];

function compileAndDeployColorContract() {

    var contractAddress = process.argv[2];
    var color = process.argv[3];

    let source = fs.readFileSync('./color.sol', 'utf8');
    let compiledContract = solc.compile(source, 1);
    let abi = compiledContract.contracts['Color'].interface;
    fs.writeFile('./colorABI.js', abi, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('colorABI.js saved!');
});
    let bytecode = compiledContract.contracts['Color'].bytecode;
    let gasEstimate = web3.eth.estimateGas({
        data: bytecode
    });
    //run out of gas when using this
    let colorContract = web3.eth.contract(JSON.parse(abi));

    //Contract Object parameters
    var deployContractObject = {
        from: account,
        data: bytecode,
        gas: '4700000'
    };

    var colorSC = colorContract.new(contractAddress, color, deployContractObject, function(err, colorSC) {
        if (!err) {
            // NOTE: The callback will fire twice!
            // Once the contract has the transactionHash property set and once its deployed on an address.

            // e.g. check tx hash on the first call (transaction send)
            if (!colorSC.address) {
                console.log('ColorTransaction Hash: ' + colorSC.transactionHash) // The hash of the transaction, which deploys the contract

                // check address on the second call (contract deployed)
            } else {
                console.log('ColorContract Mined! address: ' + colorSC.address) // the contract address

            }

            // Note that the returned "myContractReturned" === "myContract",
            // so the returned "myContractReturned" object will also get the address set.
        }
        else { console.log(err);}
    });
}

compileAndDeployColorContract();
```

I already had a look [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13827/no-data-is-deployed-in-the-contract-address), [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1582/mist-no-data-is-deployed-on-the-contract-address) and [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12386/mist-error-no-data-is-deployed-on-this-contract-address).

Thanks for your answers,

Comment: Name of constructor in you contract should be same as the name of contract. Check it . Probably you have named the constructor 'User'

Comment: Oh yeah. But I tried it again, but still the same error.

Comment: Exactly when you are getting that error, during deployment or while calling any function of contract?

Comment: During the deployment

Comment: Can you paste the complete error msg? Does you action generate any transaction hash?`console.log("Ethereum - connected to RPC server");` this line is being executed?

Answer (score 1):

This is a late reply, but i am leaving this for any future visitors
Your solidity code seems to work fine, except that the `getColor()` function would not retrieve the correct value as a result of your returns statement; try: `returns(string)`
Try making use of the browser-solidity (Remix) tool: [browser-solidity(Remix)](https://remix.ethereum.org/#version=soljson-v0.4.11+commit.68ef5810.js)  upon loading the contract code, it compiles and also provides a working web3 deployment code.

Hope this helps